# Remotely add a domain user as admin when the impersonated user doesn't have domain access

Tags: c#, active-directory, impersonation

I'm writing a remote administration tool that can grant and revoke admin rights to users on other machines in the network.

I have this configuration:

- A remote machine (machine1) with two administrative users:

  - A local admin: adminA
  - A domain user with administrative rights: domA.com\adminB
- A machine (machine2) running the admin tool, running user is not from the domA.com domain
- A domain user, domA\adminC which currently isn't an admin on machine1

I wish to grant admin rights for the domA.com\adminC user, given the credentials to a local admin user on the remote machine.

During the process, I can impersonate the **local admin** on the remote machine using the token from  advapi32.dll `LogonUser` method. In the impersonated context I'm able to use `DirectoryEntry` to find the remote machine's administrator group (using Sid). From there I can `Invoke` the `Add`/`Remove` action to add or remove the **domain** user using the path `WinNT://domA.com/adminC`.

Again - this works with an impersonated **local admin** on the remote machine, **not a domA.com user**.

If, however, I want to use `PrincipalContext`, `GroupPrincipal` and `UserPrincipal` to query this domain user permissions, add or remove it from the remote admin group - I'm unable to do so: I cannot start a `Domain` PrincipalContext without a domain user, as I'm using the local user, so I cannot get its `UserPrincipal` to add the admin `GroupPrincipal`.
This is inline with the Windows behavior - if I log on via RDP to the remote machine with the local admin, and attempt to add a domain account to its admin group, I need to provide domain credentials.

Is there a way to use PrincipalContext to add a domain user without specifying a domain user's credentials, the way that DirectoryEntry allows?

Comment: Is the storage and use of user/password a security concern in your tool? Could that be mitigated by using Azure Vault and powershell to retrieve the credentials?
Is powershell RM working on the AD computer?
Which version of powershell are you running?
What OS version is involved?